# Odoo 10 : Call a confirmation form (Yes / No) from Wizard

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add to my purchase order a 'cancel' button. This button will change the state of my record to 'canceled'.
When the user click on this button the script verify all the purchase inquiries and provider orders if there is any one not done or canceled yet.
I want to add a pop-up to warn the user about them. The user can cancel the operation or pursuit and cancel all the related inquiries and orders.

This is my wizard model :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class confirm_wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'tjara.confirm_wizard'

    yes_no = fields.Char(default='Do you want to proceed?')

    @api.multi
    def yes(self):
        return True

    @api.multi
    def no(self):
        return False
```

My wizards view :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="confirm_wizard_form">
            <field name="name">wizard.form</field>
            <field name="model">tjara.confirm_wizard</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Confirm dialog">
                    <field name="yes_no" readonly="1" />
                    <footer>
                        <button class="oe_highlight" name="yes" string="Yes" />
                        <button class="oe_highlight" name="no" string="No" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

The button :

```xml
<button string="Canceled" type="object" name="canceled_progressbar" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '=', 'done')]}"/>
```

And finally the two methods :

```py
@api.multi
def return_confirmation(self):
    return {
        'name': 'Are you sure?',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'tjara.confirm_wizard',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
    }

@api.multi
def canceled_progressbar(self):
    if(self.return_confirmation()):
        #Do some code
    else:
        #Do some code
```

The model is triggered only when the button is pointed on return_confirmation method. Which make me incapable to pursuit my code. Only a pop-up appear then disappear when the user click on a button.
I want to call the return_confirmation (pop-up) via the canceled_progressbar, so I can return the value and moving on.

Comment: Please add the button tag in in the form and add confirm attribute in button. Please refer
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-confirm-dialog-box-on-button-or-action-2054

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.
This will show just a confirm pop-up in any case.
I want to show a confirm button just in one circumstance : When the record has related entities not done yet.

Comment: @Shreeram Thank you for your reply. The confirm button is no use in my case. Please read the solution in my reply below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is what I wrote :

```
    @api.multi
    def yes(self):
        print 'yes function'
        self.env['tjara.purchase_order'].function1()

    @api.multi
    def no(self):
        print 'no function'
        self.env['purchase_order'].function1()
```

The 'canceled_progressbar' method return :

```
    @api.multi
    def canceled_progressbar(self):
        print 'canceled_progressbar'
        return {
            'name': 'Are you sure?',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'tjara.confirm_wizard',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

And I added two function according to the confirmation :

```
    @api.multi
    def function1(self):
        print 'this function 1'

    @api.multi
    def function2(self):
        print 'this function 2'
```

I was wondering if I can make only one function but it seems like impossible.

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: 1./ 'cancel_progressbar' seems to be correct 2./ You don't need separate functions 'function1' and 'function2'. 3./ Directly add your code in the clicks of 'def yes' and 'def no'.

Comment: @HardikPatadia It works well here. I don't wan't to work in the wizard page it's just about organization of code :) thank you a lot

Answer (score 5):

You can add:

```
confirm="Your Custom message like Are you sure you want to process this?"
```

in button in xml.

Comment: The is the easiest way so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the Action directly from `def canceled_progressbar` method, instead of defining it separately.

Also, I don't think your method `def return_confirmation` will be able to receive the value the way you tried by returning either 'True' or 'False'.

Here you should directly add your code in the wizard based on the clicking 'Yes' or 'No' buttons, the one that you are planning in `def return_confirmation`.