# Can we set a confirmation message for a Onchange function in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Can we set a confirmation message for a Onchange function in Odoo. if we change a field a warning will appear If we confirm we agree the chang else we need to revert the change.

Comment: I never seen something like this, before and I don't think you can show a confirmation message in onchange method

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom confirmation wizard or use redirect warning in onchange function to get a confirmation message.

Comment: @CharifDZ check this link for confirmation wizard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983595/odoo-10-call-a-confirmation-form-yes-no-from-wizard

Comment: Sorry may friend but this will work with `onchange` and there is no such thing a confirmation message in `onchange`. you can only show warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in onchange

```
 message = {'title': _('Title'),'message': _('Message')}

 return {'value': {}, 'warning':message}
```

Comment: this is a warning not a confirmation message

Comment: For that you have to create a wiard modle and call the wizard in onchange function